How to specify (declval?) a function pointer argument to a method in a concept 'requires' block?
I have a scheduler class template that I'd like to use with one of several timer classes. I'd like to use a concept to verify a given timer class has what the scheduler needs.
// One of several that will follow this pattern.
class Timer8 {
public:
  //...
  using overflow_context = OverflowIrqCtx; // a struct.
  using overflow_handler = void(*)(overflow_context* ovf_ctx, void* usr_ctx);
  void SetOverflowIrqEnabled(bool enabled);
  void SetOverflowIrqHandler(void* usr_ctx, overflow_handler handler);
  //...
};

However the following does not compile:
template<typename T>
concept Timer = requires(T a) {
  { a.SetOverflowIrqEnabled(std::declval<bool>()) };
  { a.SetOverflowIrqHandler(std::declval<void*>(), std::declval<typename T::overflow_handler>()) };
};

The error is:
scheduler.h: In substitution of 'template<class T>  requires  Timer<T> class embedded::Scheduler [with T = embedded::time::Timer8]':
scheduler_test.cc:20:45:   required from here
scheduler.h:16:9:   required for the satisfaction of 'Timer<T>' [with T = embedded::time::Timer8]
scheduler.h:16:17:   in requirements with 'T a' [with T = embedded::time::Timer8]
scheduler.h:22:28: note: the required expression 'a.SetOverflowIrqHandler(std::declval<void*>(), declval<typename T::overflow_handler>())' is invalid, because
   22 |   { a.SetOverflowIrqHandler(std::declval<void*>(), std::declval<typename T::overflow_handler>()) };
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


If I remove the function pointer declval and replace it with nullptr it compiles, but I don't think that's testing what I want it to test.
What would be the correct way to specify that a method must take a particular function pointer type as an argument in a concept? Is there some syntax gotcha I'm missing? Thanks!

Seems to work for me. To the extent there is a problem, it likely lies in the code not shown. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve].

A side note: since you use modern C++ (e.g. concepts) you can also use std::function instead of C style function pointers. It will also allow you to pass lambdas and maybe avoid the void* usr_ctx parameter which I assume is used to pass a this pointer or similar.

Huh, that is weird, I will try to comment everything else out and add it back in till I find the issue.

@wohlstad This is for an embedded environment and I'm leery of having things heap allocate when I don't want them to. I know there are cases where you can use std::function/lambdas without allocation but not enough to be confident haha.

You can add extra arguments to requires to avoid declval.

"note: the required expression [...] is invalid, because" -- Did your compiler leave you in suspense and not continue this sentence after "because"?

hmm, gcc never said "because" to me in that line, thet's a weird line. what compiler it is? Compilers may have weird bugs

It's possible this is a compiler bug or a standard library implementation issue. I was after a more modern toolchain for AVR and a modern but stripped down standard library implementation for embedded use. I found both from these fine people: https://github.com/modm-io
It's totally possible this is an old bug that's been fixed in mainline gcc, with the holidays I haven't had a chance to dive deeper on this one yet.
And yeah, the compiler totally just left me hanging at "because".
